# Error using statsmodels.api using ols().fit()

Tags: python, machine-learning, statsmodels

I have been following a tutorial on Udemy for machine learning. I am using the `statsmodels.formula.api` library but the class `OLS` was not in there and I guess it was moved because I found a thread saying to use `statsmodels.api` and it imports. The problem is that when I run the `fit()` method on `sm.OLS()`, code below, I get the error `'NoneType' Object has no attribute 'shape'` . Here's the code and the error.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
X = np.append(arr = np.ones((len(X), 1)).astype(int), values = X , axis = 1)
X_opt = X[:, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog = y, exorg = X_opt).fit()
```

Error on the line `regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog = y, exorg = X_opt).fit()`

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'`

Note: If I exclude `.fit()` as in just run `regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog = y, exorg = X_opt)`, it works without a error but it's not the result I want.

Comment: typo `exorg` -> `exog`. It's a positional argument, but python allows keyword usage if it is correctly spelled

Comment: @Josef Thanks for your help.  I figured it out. Turns out, I just had to replace `regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog = y, exorg = X_opt)` to `regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(y, X_opt)`. I'm new to this so I didn't know what the keyword args where and, my mistake, didn't read basic docs. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
X = np.append(arr = np.ones((len(X), 1)).astype(int), values = X , axis = 1)
X_opt = X[:, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog = y, exog = X_opt)
res=regressor_OLS.fit()
```

This is because you have to fit your regressor after you initialise it. ON other note just noticed it is exog not exorg

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I figured it out. Turns out, I just had to replace `regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog = y, exorg = X_opt)` to `regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(y, X_opt)`